# Moving a ROS robot in Gazebo, are plugins necessary or can I use topic/node method instead?

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I'm really newbye in Gazebo and I tried in last days to read everything I could find to use Gazebo for my simulated robot.

So far so good..I've a small robot which moves really good under RViz and now I'm interested to simulate it in Gazebo. Since the ROS Node is going to simulate the robot's dynamic I want at first move it under Gazebo. Something similar I 've found in this [question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2257/general-gazebo-questions-before-starting-with-a/).
But I'm still a little bit confused about Plugins in Gazebo.
For my understanding one could move the robot just publishing from ROS information about velocity and position on the following two topics:

```
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
```

So...now...why should I need a plugin? What's the purpose for?

Is the way (publishing on these topics) right? Or one should create a plugin of the robot to get simulated in Gazebo?

Many thanks in advance
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8666/moving-a-ros-robot-in-gazebo,-are-plugins-necessary-or-can-i-use-topic/node-method-instead?/) by [Antares](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1203/antares/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recommend you take a closer look at the Gazebo [plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_hello_world&cat=write_plugin). As it said,

> A plugin is a chunk of code that is compiled as a shared library and inserted into the simulation. The plugin has direct access to all the functionality of Gazebo through the standard C++ classes.

So if you want to use all the functionality of Gazebo(get model name, set velocity, acceleration, change simulation physics properties, etc.), not only limiting to publishing messages on /gazebo/set_link_state, /gazebo/set_model_state or other topics to change the model or link state(yes, you can publish messages on these topics to make your model move), you should learn to write a plugin.

Actually, Gazebo has been developed independent of ROS, so it is not using ROS messages, service, topics, etc any more. It adopts protobuf for message passing(take a look at "[Transport Library" tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=transport)) and you will not see ROS topics like /gazebo/set_link_state. The reason that you can use them is because a package called [gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros). As the tutorial said:

> To achieve ROS integration with stand-alone Gazebo, a new set of ROS packages named gazebo_ros_pkgs has been created to provide wrappers around the stand-alone Gazebo. They provide the necessary interfaces to simulate a robot in Gazebo using ROS messages, services and dynamic reconfigure.

Now I am using model plugin to control my robot and works well. Actually, if you want to move your robot in simulation, I think it is better to use gazebo function [SetAngularVel()](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/5.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#a97be587041d6a07fe650c86678099c0c) or [SetLinearVel()](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/5.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#acb848e605587a69dfc0c5342905f1e3c) instead of publishing messages on topic /gazebo/set_model_state. Because messages on the topic /gazebo/set_model_state have fields of both velocity and pose and it is tricky to set both of them.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1